# Google API : live server firewall ip address ranges

Tags: google-api, ip, firewall

We are calling Google api via https://www.googleapis.com for social login on our website. Everything works fine upto staging , however on Live server due to firewall restriction api calls are throwing socket exception.

What is the best way to configure our live server to allow connectivity to Google.

Is there a list of ip addresses . How can I make sure it's all up to date.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: You must be using Google Maps for Work (paid) in order to host maps on a website that is behind a firewall. Otherwise you are in breach of the terms of service.**

As for configuring your firewall, Google will provide you with all of the settings that are needed. You don't need to make constant changes to keep it working.

The primary source of information for configuring your firewall is found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/prelaunch_checklist#firewall

**Configure Firewall to Allow Access to the Google Maps API Services**

**Why it's important:** The Maps API services use a variety of domains, some which do not belong to the *google.com domain. If you are behind a restrictive firewall, it is important you understand which Maps API services use which domains.

Failure to allow access to the correct domains will cause API requests to fail, which can break your applications. For a complete listing of domains used by the Maps APIs, please consult our [portal resource](http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal) (login required):

Log in to the [Google Enterprise Support Portal](http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal)
The support portal is only available to Google Maps API for Work users.
Navigate to the "Resources" tab
Select the Resource called ["List of domains used by the Google Maps API Family."](https://na4.salesforce.com/a0Z60000000hXGe)
You should allow your applications to access these domains.

Please note that we do not recommend managing firewall restrictions by IP address, as the IPs associated with these domains are not static.

Comment: Please provide feedback on why you downvoted this answer so that it can be improved.